# Taylor's series around zero of $e^{-1/x^2}$?

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

Consider the following piecewise function:

$f(x)=e^{-1/x^2}$ if $x \neq 0$, and $f(x)=0$ if $x=0$.

I'm trying to write her Taylor's series around $x=0$ but I'm stuck because calculating the derivative of $f(x)$ and evaluating at $x=0$ is not so straightforward, due to the evaluation needs to take the limit $x->0$.

Questions:
1. Which formal criteria or theorem can I use to justify that $f^{(n)}(0)=\lim_{x->0}f^{(n)}(x)$?
2. Is there a direct way of writing the complete Taylor's series without computing a lot of derivatives and limits?

Comment: A priori, for an everywhere differentiable function $f$, $\lim_{x\to0}f'(x)$ needn't even exist. It does in this case, but there are counterexamples.

Comment: It is quite a famous "counter-example"; a smooth function that is zero only in the origin, but all derivatives in $0$ are zero, so the Taylor is zero as well. You can show this by proving $f(x)\in o(x^n)$ for all $n$.

Answer (score 2):

By the  MVT you show that if for $k\geq 1$:

- $f\in C^{k-1}$ in a neighborhood $U$ of 0,
- $f\in C^k$ in the punctured neighborhood $U\setminus\{0\}$   and
- $\ell=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} f^{(k)}(x)$ exists
  then $f\in C^k(U)$ and $f^{(n)}(0)=\ell$.

In the present context you would usually first show that 
$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{P(x)}{x^m} e^{-1/x^2}=0$ for any polynomial $P$, and any $m\geq 1$ and then use induction and the above statement.

Comment: Any reference (book), please? I'm newbie in this formal topics.

Comment: Unfortunately no, I have looked through my books on analysis and either they just assume it or leaves it as an exercise to the reader. Is your exercise in some context?

Comment: Found this, which treats almost the same problem (from p 199): http://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~hunter/intro_analysis_pdf/ch10.pdf